Calculate the approximate value of $z=\ln(10.3 + \sqrt {4.4})$ where $x^*=10.3$ and $y^*=4.4$ are safe figures
The following is an exercise from my Numerical Mathematics/Methods class, but currently I'm self studying from notes and there is a lot in the solution I don't understand.
The exercise:

Calculate the approximate value of $z=\ln(10.3 + \sqrt 4.4)$ where $x^*=10.3$ and $y^*=4.4$ are safe figures.

First off, I couldn't find the translation of what we call the "safe figures" so here is how we defined it:

Definition. Let $a \in \mathbb R$ and $\overline a$ be its approximation and $\Delta(\overline a)=|a - \overline a|$ the absolute error of $\overline a$. A safe figure $\alpha^k$ is a significant figure for which it holds $\omega10^{n-k}<\Delta(\overline a)\leq \omega 10^{n-k+1}$, for $0<\omega\leq1$. (Note that $\alpha_k$ the is the $k$-th digit in decimal expansion of $\overline a$.)

The solution starts with $$\begin{align}\Delta x^* &\leq \frac{1}{2}10^{-1}=0,05 \quad \quad |x-x^*|\leq 0,05\\ \Delta y^* &\leq \frac{1}{2}10^{-1}=0,05 \quad \quad |y-y^*|\leq 0,05 \end{align}$$
I guess we can choose $\omega = 1/2$ because the condition from the definition of the safe figure is satisified (and there's a remark that the value of $1/2$ is most commonly used---something I don't fully understand but I'm ok with just memorizing for now), but how did we get that $-1$ in $10^{-1}$ ? In essence I don't understand what are the $n$ and $k$ from the safe figure definition in this case, or perhaps I don't understand how the definition of $k$-th digit in the decimal expansion of $\overline a$ being a safe one  relates to $\overline a$ being a safe figure itself. Maybe some usual abuse of terminology happened in the statement of the problem but I don't see how, and perhaps someone who is familiar with this stuff will recognize what's up.
Then it proceeds with using Lagrange's theorem like following let $u(y) = \sqrt y$ then we have $$\begin{align}|u(y)-u(y^*)| = |u'(\xi)-(y-y^*)| &\iff \Delta u^* \leq |u'(\xi)|\Delta y^* \leq |u'(\xi)|\\ &\color{red} \implies y \in [4.35, 4.45]\end{align}$$
How did we get the last implication? I guess it's $y^* \pm 0.05$ the bound we got earlier, but I don't see the reasoning behind it. As I write this, I get the sense that this process was "engineered" to arrive at these values via Lagrange.
Next we have $$u'(\xi) \leq \frac{1}{2\sqrt{4.35}} \implies \Delta u^* \leq \frac{1}{2\sqrt{4.35}}\frac{1}{2}10^{-1}=0,12\cdot 10^{\color {red} {-1}}$$
(I understand this but I include it for completion. Also the red exponent $-1$ at the end is circled for some reason)
and thus $u^*=\sqrt{4.4} = 2.1$, which is what I get either way just calculating $\sqrt{4.4}$ so it doesn't help me get the point of what we just did.
I'm omitting the rest of the solution since it proceeds in the same manner but compositionally with $v^*=10.3 + 2.1=12.4$ and then $\Delta v^*=1/2 10^{-1} + 0.12 10^{-1}=0.62$ ... If necessary I'll make another post about this latter part, but for now the above is where I'm stuck at.

$1<\omega\leq1$ is a self-contradictory expression.  Is that a typo?

@Dan yes, thanks. it should be $0$ on LHS. fixed it

If you simply plug the expression into a calculator, you get $z \approx 2.5175043328904585$.  But that doesn't account for the uncertainty in the numbers.
If I'm understanding the “safe figures” definition correctly, your textbook is assuming that the numbers are correctly rounded to the unit in the least-significant digits place (with $\omega = \frac{1}{2}$ being the maximum error allowed in that last place).  That is, 10.3 denotes a true value between $10.25$ and $10.35$, and 4.4 denotes a true value between $4.35$ and $4.45$.  Since the $\ln$ and √ operators are both strictly increasing on the positive reals, that means
$$\ln(10.25 + \sqrt {4.35}) \le z \le \ln(10.35 + \sqrt {4.45})$$
$$2.512494689463846 \le z \le 2.522483569621992$$
$$-0.005009643426612698 \le z - 2.5175043328904585 \le 0.004979236731533554$$
$$|z - 2.5175043328904585| \le 0.005009643426612698$$
So, the maximum error in the value of $z$ is close to $0.005$, which is basically saying that $z$ is correct to two decimal places.  That is, $\boxed{z \approx 2.52}$.

However, it's not always practical to explicitly calculate the error bounds like that.  So you can approximate the uncertainty with derivatives.  Let $z = \ln(x + \sqrt{y})$.  Then,
$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = \frac{1}{x + \sqrt{y}} = \frac{x - \sqrt{y}}{x^2 - y}$$
$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}(x + \sqrt{y})} = \frac{y - x\sqrt{y}}{2y(y - x^2)}$$
Plugging in $x = 10.3$ and $y = 4.4$ gives $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} \approx 0.08066065791778639$ and $\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} \approx 0.019226729937136398$.  Combining these two partial derivatives to get a total derivative gives:
$$dz = \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} ~dx + \frac{\partial z}{\partial y} ~dy$$
$$\approx 0.08066065791778639 \times 0.05 + 0.019226729937136398 \times 0.05$$
$$\approx 0.004994369392746139$$
Which is very close to (only $0.3\%$ less than) the “exact” uncertainty value found earlier.
Your book is breaking down the derivative calculation into multiple steps by starting with the innermost function $u(y) = \sqrt y \implies u'(y) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}}$, and then apparently defining $v(x, y) = x + \sqrt{y}$ and $z = \sqrt{v}$.


but how did we get that $−1$ in $10^{−1}$?

Because the values of $x$ and $y$ are given rounded to the nearest multiple of $0.1$, which can also be written as $10^{-1}$.

I see, this clarifies a lot. thank you. btw, I believe that $4.435$ is a typo

@powerline: Yes, it was a typo.  I just fixed it.

hey, how does the $u'(\xi)$ from the usage of Lagrange's theorem in my question relate to your method with partial derivatives?

@powerline: $u'$ is the source of the $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}}$ factor in $\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$.
